# Why JButton is not working when a thread is running?

Tags: java, swing

There are 2 buttons in my application. When "Start" button is pressed, I created a thread to update the JTextArea. When "Stop" button is pressed, I wanted to stop the thread. But when "Start" is pressed, the "Stop" is not working until the thread is completed. Could anyone help me?

```
public class JTextAreaDemo implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel jp;
    JTextArea jta;
    JButton jb1, jb2;
    volatile boolean stop = true;

    void init() {
        frame=new JFrame("Test"); 
        jp=new JPanel(); 
        jta=new JTextArea(7,30);
        jb1 = new JButton("Start");
        jb1.addActionListener(this);
        jb2 = new JButton("Stop");
        jb2.addActionListener(this);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        jta.setLineWrap(true); 
        jta.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
        JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(jta);   
        Dimension size=jta.getPreferredSize();   
        jsp.setBounds(110,90,size.width,size.height);
        jp.add(jsp);   
        jp.add(jb1);
        jp.add(jb2);
        frame.add(jp);  
        frame.setSize(400,200);   
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTextAreaDemo().init();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == jb1) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=0; i<100000 && stop; ++i) {
                    final String str = "hello:"+i+"\n";
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            jta.append(str);
                            jta.setCaretPosition(jta.getDocument().getLength());

                        });
                    }
                }   
            }).start();
            System.out.println("begin");
        } else if (e.getSource() == jb2) {
            System.out.println("stop");
            stop = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` puts an action on a queue to be executed later. Your loop `for(int i=0; i<100000 && stop; ++i)` will very quickly put one hundred thousand actions on the queue and be done. It will be done before you press stop.

After that, all the actions get executed.

One way to address this is to use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`. This will also put an action on the queue, but it will then wait for the Swing thread to execute that action before moving on. This means that the loop itself will take as long to complete as all the actions that it is scheduling, and it will see the change to the `stop` flag.

(Note: you may consider renaming `stop` to `keepRunning` - because currently, you want to stop when you set `stop` to `false`.)